# Can I share state between two EmberJS apps

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm trying to see if there is a possibility to share state (with ember-data) or any addon that can be added to it - if there is a possibility to share state between two (or more) separated EmberJS web applications? I have found a way to share the state of course only internally within the same web app but not between different web apps.

Comment: Have a look at [Ember Engines](https://ember-engines.com/)

Comment: do they run under the same domain? have a look how `ember-simple-auth` utilizes the `localStorage`

Comment: I'm looking now at ember-engines yes - will it share the whole context of the containing application that runs it?